# VF: SOQL Query - if then variable

Tags: apex, visualforce

Ok, I am sure this is staring me in the face but I can't find my issue.

My page passes the value of the checkbox back to controller. I verified in logs that the value is coming across correctly.

HOWEVER my if then statement on showAll doesn't seem to want to work. I always get the hubFilter value of BCS%.

VF Page:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!showAll}">
                    Show All Hubs
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!showAllFilter}" rerender="thePage" status="tbloading">
                        <apex:param name="showAll" assignTo="{!showAll}" value="TRUE"/>
                    </apex:actionSupport>
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
```

Controller:

```
    public class LicensingGridController {

        public Id selectedHubId {get; set;}
        public Boolean AccRendered {get; set;}
        public Boolean bcsPaging {get; set;}
        public Boolean showAll {get; set;}
        public String stFilter {get; set;}
        public String bcsFilter {get; set;}
        list<BCS__c>hubs = new list<BCS__c>();
        String[] states = new String[]{};
        private string hubfilter;

        //Pagination
        private integer totalrec=0;
        private integer limitsize=5;
        public integer offsetsize {get; set;}

        public LicensingGridController(){
            AccRendered     = FALSE;
            bcspaging       = TRUE;
            offsetsize      = 0;
            showAll         = FALSE;
        }

        public List<BCS__c> getTheHubs() {
            system.debug('stfilter = ' + stFilter);
            system.debug('states = '+ states);
            system.debug('showall = '+ showAll);

            if(showAll == TRUE){
                hubFilter = '%';
            }else{
                hubFilter = 'BCS%';
            }

            if(states.isEmpty()){            
                totalrec= [Select Count()
                           FROM BCS__c
                           WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE];

                hubs = [Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,User__r.SmallPhotoUrl,Title__c,
                        (Select Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                         FROM Account_Counselors__r
                         ORDER BY Account__r.Name ASC),
                        (Select Name,Status__c,Status_Icon__c 
                         FROM Licenses__r
                         WHERE Status__c = 'Current'
                         ORDER BY NAME ASC
                        )
                        FROM BCS__c
                        WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE
                        AND Title__c LIKE :hubFilter
                        ORDER BY Name ASC
                        LIMIT :limitsize 
                        OFFSET :offsetsize];
                return hubs;
            } else { 
                totalrec= [Select Count()
                           FROM BCS__c
                           WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE AND 
                           id in (select Hub_Name__c from LIcense__c where Name IN :states)];

                if(totalrec <= limitsize){
                    bcspaging = false;    
                }

                hubs = [Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,User__r.SmallPhotoUrl,Title__c,
                        (Select Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                         FROM Account_Counselors__r
                         ORDER BY Account__r.Name ASC),
                        (Select Name,Status__c,Status_Icon__c 
                         FROM Licenses__r
                         WHERE Status__c = 'Current'
                         ORDER BY NAME ASC
                        )
                        FROM BCS__c
                        WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE
                        AND Title__c LIKE :hubFilter
                        AND id in (select Hub_Name__c from LIcense__c where Name IN :states)
                        ORDER BY Name ASC
                        LIMIT :limitsize 
                        OFFSET :offsetsize];

                system.debug('thehubs = ' + hubs);
                system.debug('offset = ' + offsetsize);
                system.debug('limitzie = ' + limitsize);

                return hubs;

            }

        }

    public PageReference showAllFilter(){
        return null;

    }

...
```

Comment: Question - have you tried using a string variable to manage the if then, rather than passing a boolean in quotes ie "TRUE" ?

Comment: showAll is a String variable.  change TRUE to 'TRUE' and it should work (single quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `apex:inputCheckbox` is too complicated because you are binding both a VF boolean and a VF string to the same controller Boolean property `showAll`

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!showAll}">
                    Show All Hubs
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!showAllFilter}" rerender="thePage" status="tbloading">
       <apex:param name="showAll" assignTo="{!showAll}" value="TRUE"/>
    </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

You should only need

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!showAll}">
    Show All Hubs
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePage" status="tbloading"/>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

The `actionSupport` + `rerender` tells VF to do an ajax refresh and the value of all fields on the form will be transmitted to the controller setters. `value="{!showAll}"` sends the checkbox value to the controller Boolean setter `showAll`. If you only want the checkbox value to transmit, wrap the `inputCheckbox` in an `actionRegion`

When the page refreshes, the VF page reference to `{!theHubs}` will then retrieve the list of `hubs`

Note, that unlike sobject checkbox fields that can only have a value of **true** or **false**, Boolean VF controller properties that are not sobjects can have three values: **null**, **true**, and **false**. Often, I end up writing the getter for these like:

```
public Boolean isX {get {return this.isX == null ? false : this.isX;} set;}
```